# How can I view a previous revision of a git repository?

Tags: git

I want to view a previous rev of a git repository. I am looking for the equivalent of tortoisesvn export of a particular revision. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view a particular file you can use `git show <hash_or_branch_name_or_tag_name> filename` to see it.

Otherwise you should do a `git checkout` of that commit hash to see it.

Comment: Tag names can also be used here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll first want to list the contents of the repository using `git log`, and then `git show <hash>` to print that revision on the screen.  If you want to limit the output to a single file, you can add `-- <file / path>` to the end of each command.

Answer (score 0):

Search revision by:

```
git log
```

remember the `hash` of the commit and check out the commit by

```
git checkout -b <hash>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried 'git show hash -- file'. It gave a diff output.

I tried 'git checkout -b hash'. It created a new branch.

What worked for me was 'git checkout hash'.